# Visual Studio 2017 Tools -> Android disabled

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

When I try to run a new blank Android app I get an error:

> "The Android SDK Directory could not be found...".

I searched in google for a solution and I found out that I need to go to `Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager`, and then I realized the buttons are disabled.

**I did some checks:**
in `Tools -> Options -> Android Setting` for Android SDK Location and it's empty. Furthermore, the folder `Programs Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk` contain only 1 folder named `extras`

I did a VS repair, twice, and nothing changed.

As I understand the problem, I don't have SDK and somehow VS can't install it properly.

**Is there any manual way to install it or any other solution?**

**Edit**: I've tried to uninstall Visual Studio and install again. It couldn't install everything successfully, here is the log:

> Package 'JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.6,chip=x64' failed to install.
>       Search URL
>           https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=JavaJDKV2;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-1
>       Details
>           Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.6,chip=x64\jdk-8u181-windows-x64.exe" /quiet
>           Return code: -1
>           Return code details: Unknown error (0xffffffff)
>       Log
>           C:\Users******\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180828172213_290_JavaJDKV2.log
>       Impacted workloads
>           Mobile development with .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.8.27906.1)
>       Impacted components
>           Android SDK setup (API level 27) (Component.Android.SDK27,version=15.8.27906.1)
>           Google Android Emulator (API Level 27) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API27,version=15.8.27906.1)
>           Java SE Development Kit (8.0.1120.15) (Component.JavaJDK,version=15.6.27406.0)

Comment: Have you tried installing sdk using android sdk manager ?  you can find it in  Tools-> Android-->android sdk manager

Comment: Everything under Tools -> Android is disabled

Comment: probably you are facing this issue because Android SDK Platform-tools is been uninstalled [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949446/android-bat-file-is-missing-in-sdk-tools-folder-also-i-do-not-having-avd-sdk-m) check this

Comment: In that answer, the path of where to put the 'tools' folder is not mentioned. I tried to put it in Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk, it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to put the path where your android-sdk has been installed in my case its C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it and here is what worked for me:

1. I downloaded the [Android Command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)
2. I put the downloaded folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
3. I opened CMD and directed to that folder.
4. I've checked the command `sdkmanager --list`, see [sdkmanager page](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) for more information
5. And I downloaded via the sdkmanager commands the SDKs I needed
6. Also, VS2017's SDK manager started to work as well after I downloaded what I needed from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest version of  "sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip" in https://developer.android.com/studio this web site and update your visual studio to latest version

this will surely work because even in my case it was same error for 3days then i did these changes and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Install Android studio - `https://developer.android.com/studio`
Open Android studio -> configure -> copy Android SDK location
Open Visual studio -> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> paste your SDK location
Done!